# How to use Spring Reactive WebSocket and transform it into the Flux stream?

Tags: spring-websocket, spring-webflux

There is some `WebSocketClient` example on [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.M4/spring-framework-reference/html/web-reactive.html):

```
WebSocketClient client = new ReactorNettyWebSocketClient();
client.execute("ws://localhost:8080/echo"), session -> {...}).blockMillis(5000);
```

Im not sure how to handle stream of incomming data?
Inside that block `{...}`.

I mean: how can I filter incoming data and cast it into Flux?

Here is what I want to get.

```
@GetMapping("/stream", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
    public Flux<MyRecourse> getStreaming() {

    //  get some data from WebSocket (CoinCap service).
    //  Transform that data into MyRecourse object
    //  Return stream to a client 

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take a look into that `WebSocketSession` param of the `WebSocketHandler.handle()` lambda:

```
/**
 * Get the flux of incoming messages.
 */
Flux<WebSocketMessage> receive();
```

See [Spring WebFlux Workshop](https://bclozel.github.io/webflux-workshop/#_create_and_configure_a_websockethandler) for more information.

**UPDATE**

Let's try this!

```
    Mono<Void> sessionMono =
            client.execute(new URI("ws://localhost:8080/echo"),
                    session ->
                            Mono.empty()
                                    .subscriberContext(Context.of(WebSocketSession.class, session))
                                    .then());

    return sessionMono
            .thenMany(
                    Mono.subscriberContext()
                            .flatMapMany(c -> c
                                    .get(WebSocketSession.class)
                                    .receive()))
            .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText);
```

**UPDATE 2**

Or another option but with blocked subscription:

```
    EmitterProcessor<String> output = EmitterProcessor.create();

    client.execute(new URI("ws://localhost:8080/echo"),
            session ->
                    session.receive()
                            .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
                            .subscribeWith(output)
                            .then())
            .block(Duration.ofMillis(5000));

    return output;
```

**UPDATE 3**

The working Spring Boot application on the matter: https://github.com/artembilan/sandbox/tree/master/websocket-over-webflux

The main code is like:

```
    EmitterProcessor<String> output = EmitterProcessor.create();

    Mono<Void> sessionMono =
            client.execute(new URI("ws://localhost:8080/echo"),
                    session -> session.receive()
                            .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
                            .subscribeWith(output)
                            .then());

    return output.doOnSubscribe(s -> sessionMono.subscribe());
```

Comment: I dont understand how to cast Flux<WebSocketMessage> to the Flux<MyObj> and return result stream.

Comment: Hm. I wonder how is it related to the original request... please, be specific with your questions here on SO. Anyway there is just `Flux.map()` on the matter to convert that `WebSocketMessage` to your `MyObj`

Comment: Artem is right, different question. Spring WebFlux only supports raw websocket for now (not yet STOMP and higher level messaging abstractions). With raw websocket, you do have to take care of your own "protocol" for that.

Comment: Yes, but how can I get Flux<String> from  Flux<WebSocketMessage>?     

`client.execute(uri, session -> session.receive().map(webSocketMessage -> {
            return Flux.just(webSocketMessage.getPayloadAsText());

        }));`
  
Error:(67, 61) java: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
no instance(s) of type variable(s) V,T exist so that reactor.core.publisher.Flux<V> conforms to reactor.core.publisher.Mono<java.lang.Void>

Comment: `session.receive().map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)`

Comment: I understand. but how can I finish that cast and return Flux? `WebSocketHandler socketHandler = (session) -> session.receive().map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText).then();
        client.execute(uri, socketHandler);
        Flux<String> result = ???;
        return result;`

Comment: Good question! Let me think about that aside :-)

Comment: And that is was my original question =) I would like to create flux API, and get some third party data from different sources. So I would like to listern Socket but return Flux.

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer. Sorry I don't have time to check it: need to warm up the environment to play with that, but maybe would be useful for you

Comment: oh. Does not work for me. The first one gives me empty browser console/network. The second one Timeout error. Im trying to [connect to that source](https://github.com/CoinCapDev/CoinCap.io) .

Comment: What? We talk about `WebSocketClient`. How the browser is related here?

Comment: Im using SpringFlux to provide responce via Rest WebService.

Comment: Br-r. And now you talk about REST... I guess it’s time to share your application with us for better understanding. Thanks

Comment: Sorry If Im not clear. I added some example what I want to get. Actually you are right. that is not "REST API". Just stream with updating data.

Comment: Sure! I see what you mean. I’ll do something on the matter tomorrow

Comment: See an UPDATE 3 in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158200/discussion-between-aleksey-kozel-and-artem-bilan).

Comment: one more question here. Could you please provide some example with sending message (i need to subscribe to events), listerning for the responces. and recconnecting to the socket if it failed?

Comment: Seems for me that deserves its own separate big SO question.

Comment: Coult you please see this topic? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47347006/examples-of-use-reactornettywebsocketclient

Comment: Yes, I can. But I can't answer to it. Sorry. I'm not sure in the reconnection feature

Comment: but probably you have an idea about another cases?

Comment: Sure! It is here: https://bclozel.github.io/webflux-workshop/#_integration_tests_with_websocketclient

Comment: Hi, In this approach what happens when there is an error on `sessionMono` i.e. `errorwhileconnecting` ? Right now a error is thrown as `ErrorCallbackNotImplemented`

Comment: `EmitterProcessor` is deprecated

Comment: Yes, the answer is 5 years old , so that’s not a surprise to see some things deprecated and removed since there. See `Sinks.Many` instead. I’m not sure that I have to go over all my thousands answers here on SO to keep them up to date…

Comment: @ArtemBilan the github example link no more working

Comment: Have just update the link in the answer. Thank you for spotting!

Comment: @ArtemBilan Thank you for modifying the link. One question though, do you know how to specify proxy settings in `org.springframework.web.reactive.socket.client.StandardWebSocketClient`? Without specifiying proxy setting, the client is not able to connect to the websocket server.

Comment: The `StandardWebSocketClient` is based on the `jakarta.websocket.WebSocketContainer`. So, you probably need to consult with your WebSocket provider how to do that in their implementation. Looks like Tomcat doesn't have too much options: https://www.jvmhost.com/articles/proxying-websockets-to-tomcat/