# Cannot use 'subscribe' or 'subscribeWith' with 'ReactorNettyWebSocketClient' in Kotlin

Tags: websocket, kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor

The Kotlin code below successfully connects to a Spring WebFlux server, sends a message and prints each message sent via the stream that is returned.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val uri = URI("ws://localhost:8080/myservice")
    val client = ReactorNettyWebSocketClient()

    val input = Flux.just(readMsg())

    client.execute(uri) { session ->
        session.send(input.map(session::textMessage))
            .thenMany(
                session.receive()
                    .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
                    .doOnNext(::println) // want to replace this call
                    .then()
            ).then()

    }.block()
}
```

In previous experience with Reactive programming I have always used **subscribe** or **subscribeWith** where the call to **doOnNext** occurs. However it will not work in this case. I understand that this is because neither returns the reactive stream in use - **subscribe** returns a **Disposable** and **subscribeWith** returns the **Subscriber** it received as a parameter.

My question is whether invoking **doOnNext** is really the correct way to add a handler to process incoming messages? 
Most Spring 5 tutorials show code which either calls this or **log**, but some use **subscribeWith(output).then()** without specifying what **output** should be. I cannot see how the latter would even compile.

Comment: do you have examples of such subscribeWith tutorials?

Comment: Here you go...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47347006/examples-of-use-reactornettywebsocketclient

Answer (score 1):

`subscribe` and `subscribeWith` should always be used right at the end of a chain of operators, not as intermediate operators.

Comment: Thats what I'm getting at. I want to specify the final action that will be performed against the payload of a WebSocketMessage. In all my use of Rx so far 'subscribe' or 'subscribeWith' would be the appropriate choice, but here it seems to have to be 'doOnNext'. Hence I'm asking why the final thing I want to do does not qualify as the end of the chain of operators?

Comment: ah, got it. in the reactor-netty API, your final processing is actually part of a larger chain that encompasses more of the server's lifecycle. That's why you have to return a `Flux` (or `Publisher`), and thus can't use `subscribe`. Same in Spring WebFlux, where the framework subscribes.

Comment: I figured it had to be something like that. But this seems a clear violation of the 'principle of least surprise' - given that its a stream handed to me by the API and I have a terminal operation I want to perform. At a minimum I would expect to find it more clearly documented.

Answer (score 0):

Simon already provided the answer but I'll add some extra context.

When composing asynchronous logic with Reactor (and ReactiveX patterns) you build an end-to-end chain of processing steps, which includes not only the logic of the `WebSocketHandler` itself but also that of the underlying WebSocket framework code responsible for sending and receiving messages to and from the socket. It's very important for the entire chain to be connected together, so that at runtime "signals" will flow through it (onNext, onError, or onComplete) from start to end and communicate the final result, i.e where you have the `.block()` at the end.

In the case of WebSocket this looks a little daunting because you're essentially combining two or more streams into one. You can't just subscribe to one of those streams (e.g. for inbound messages) because that prevents composing a unified processing stream, and signals will not flow through to the end where the final outcome is expected.

The other side of this is that `subscribe()` triggers consumption on a stream whereas what you really want is to keep composing asynchronous logic in deferred  mode, i.e. declaring all that will happen when data materializes. This is another reason why composing a single unified chain is important. So it can be triggered after it is fully declared.

In short the main difference with the imperative `WebSocketHandler` for the Servlet world, is that instead of it being a handler for individual messages, this is a handler for composing the complete streams. Here the handling of an individual message is just one step of the overall processing chain. So the only place to subscribe is at the very end, where `.block()` is, in order to kick off processing.

BTW since this question was first posted a few months ago, the documentation has been improved to [provide more guidance](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-websockethandler) on how to implement a `WebSocketHandler`.