# How to ensure Reactive Stream completes with Spring WebFlux and WebSockets

Tags: websocket, kotlin, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have written a test client and server for Spring WebFlux in Kotlin. The client sends a number to the server (e.g. 4) and gets back that many numbers (e.g. 0, 1, 2 and 3). Here is the server implementation:

```
class NumbersWebSocketHandler : WebSocketHandler {
    override fun handle(session: WebSocketSession): Mono<Void> {
        var index = 0
        var count = 1
        val publisher = Flux.generate<Int> { sink ->
            if (index < count) {
                sink.next(index)
                index++
            } else {
                sink.complete()
            }
        }.map(Int::toString)
            .map(session::textMessage)
            .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(500))

        return session.receive()
            .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
            .doOnNext {
                println("About to send $it numbers")
                count = it.toInt()
            }
            .then()
            .and(session.send(publisher))
            .then()
    }
}
```

And here is the client:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val uri = URI("ws://localhost:8080/numbers")
    val client = ReactorNettyWebSocketClient()

    println("How many numbers would you like?")
    val input = Flux.just(readLine())

    client.execute(uri) { session ->
        session.send(input.map(session::textMessage))
            .then(
                session.receive()
                    .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
                    .map { it.toInt() }
                    .reduce { a,b ->
                        println("Reduce called with $a and $b")
                        a + b
                    }
                    .doOnNext(::println)
                    .then()
            )
            .then()
    }.block()
}
```

The client successfully receives the numbers and reduce is invoked as below:

> Reduce called with 0 and 1
>
> Reduce called with 1 and 2
>
> Reduce called with 3 and 3

However the call to **doOnNext** is never reached - presumably because the client is unaware that the last item has been sent. My question is what code do I need to add, on either client or server, for the total to be printed?

**UPDATE:** Closing the session on the server side does not help. I have tried:

```
.delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(500))
.doOnComplete { session.close() }
```

And also:

```
.delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(500))
.doFinally { session.close() }
```

But neither have any affect on the behaviour of the client. Neither does trying to close the session explicitly after the call to 'send':

```
.and(session.send(publisher))
.then()
.and { session.close() }
.then()
```

Comment: You can use the `take()` operator because you know how many items you will receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Mono<Void>` returned from a `WebSocketHandler` indicates when handling is complete, that in turn indicates how long the WebSocket connection should remain open. The problem is that on both sides the `Mono<Void>` returned will never complete.

The client uses `reduce` which waits for the end of input from the server side, but the server uses `receive()` + `doOnNext` + `then()` which waits to receive messages forever. So client and server both wait for each other. Adding `take` on the client side helps to break the stalemate:

```
client.execute(uri, session -> session
        .send(input.map(session::textMessage))
        .then(session.receive()
                .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
                .map(Integer::valueOf)
                .take(3)
                .reduce((a,b) -> {
                    logger.debug("Reduce called with " + a + " and " + b);
                    return a + b;
                })
                .doOnNext(logger::debug)
        )
        .then()
).block();
```

The second issue is that the server is incorrectly composed. The sending is triggered in parallel with receiving via `.and`. Instead the sending stream should depend on receiving the count first:

```
session.receive()
        .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
        .flatMap(s -> {
            logger.debug("About to send " + s + " numbers");
            count.set(Integer.parseInt(s));
            return session.send(publisher);
        })
        .then()
```

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen from the [marble diagram for `reduce`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reactor/reactor-core/v3.1.3.RELEASE/src/docs/marble/aggregate.png), it expects the upstream publisher to send an `onComplete` event to emit an event itself. I am not sure but I think that's emitted only when the connection is terminated gracefully. That's why the `doOnNext` is never executed.

Instead of `reduce` I think you should use the `subscribe()` instead, and define your own `Subscriber` instance where you could keep the state.

**EDIT:** You can't use a `subscribe` method here. Though it should work like this if the connection is closed on server:

```
.map(Int::toString)
        .map(session::textMessage)
        .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(500))
        .then(session::close)
```

Comment: That begs the question of why the connection is not being terminated gracefully? What has been left out on the server side? Also 'subscribe' cannot be used with 'ReactorNettyWebSocketClient' because of the way they have designed the API. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49590325/cannot-use-subscribe-or-subscribewith-with-reactornettywebsocketclient-in

Comment: That's because server doesn't call `close()` when the initial stream ends:
`...().delayElements(...).then(session::close);`

Comment: Or rather I can write 'delayElements(...).doOnComplete { session.close() }' or 'delayElements(...).doFinally { session.close() }' but neither affects the output. A call to '.then(...)' does not compile at that position.