# Blocking timeout exception in Spring reactive WebSocketClient

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-websocket

The [websocket sample project](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/tree/websocket/websocket) is based on Spring 5.3( and dependencies managed by Boot 2.5.6).

On the server side, I created a `WebSocketHandlder` to handle WebSocket request.

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MessagetHandler implements WebSocketHandler {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    private Sinks.Many<Message> sinks = Sinks.many().replay().limit(2);
    private Flux<Message> outputMessages = sinks.asFlux();

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession session) {
        var receiveMono = session.receive()
                .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
                .map(this::readIncomingMessage)
                .map(req -> Message.builder().id(UUID.randomUUID()).body(req.message()).sentAt(LocalDateTime.now()).build())
                .log("server receiving::")
//                .subscribe(
//                        data -> sinks.emitNext(data, Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.FAIL_FAST),
//                        error -> sinks.emitError(error, Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.FAIL_FAST)
//                );
                .doOnNext(data -> sinks.emitNext(data, Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.FAIL_FAST))
                .doOnError(error -> sinks.emitError(error, Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.FAIL_FAST))
                .then();

        // TODO: workaround for suspected RxNetty WebSocket client issue
        // https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxNetty/issues/560
        var sendMono = session
                .send(
                        Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(500))
                                .thenMany(outputMessages.map(msg -> session.textMessage(toJsonString(msg))))
                )
                .log("server sending::")
                .onErrorResume(throwable -> session.close())
                .then();

        return Mono.zip(receiveMono, sendMono).then();
    }
//...
}
```

I wrote a test to send WebSocket request via WebSocketClient(`NettReactiveWebSocketClient`).

```java
 Sinks.Many<Message> sinks = Sinks.many().replay().limit(2);
        // var latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        var socketUri = URI.create("ws://localhost:" + port + "/ws/messages");

        WebSocketHandler handler = session -> {

            var receiveMono = session.receive()
                    .map(it -> it.getPayloadAsText())
                    .map(text -> readMessage(text))
                    .log("client receiving::")
                    .doOnNext(data -> sinks.emitNext(data, Sinks.EmitFailureHandler.FAIL_FAST)).then();
            //.subscribe(data -> replayList.add(data));

            var sendMono = session
                    .send(
                            Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(100)).thenMany(
                                    Flux.just("message one", "message two").map(m -> session.textMessage(toJsonString(m)))
                            )
                    )
                    .log("client sending::")
                    //.then(Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(1000)).then(session.close(CloseStatus.NORMAL)))
                    .then();
            return sendMono.then(receiveMono);
        };

        this.client.execute(socketUri, handler)
                 //       .block(Duration.ofMillis(1000));
                .subscribe();

        // latch.await();
        // assertThat(replayList.size()).isEqualTo(2);

        StepVerifier.create(sinks.asFlux())
                .consumeNextWith(it -> assertThat(it.getBody()).isEqualTo("message one"))
                .consumeNextWith(it -> assertThat(it.getBody()).isEqualTo("message two"))
                .expectComplete()
                .verify();
```

If I used `this.client.execute(socketUri, handler).subscribe()` here, **it is always blocked and not exited the console**.

If I used  `this.client.execute(socketUri, handler).block(Duratoin.of...)`, it will throw an exception complaining **blocking timeout**. But I have used this approach in a former example project, it worked well for both cases(used `subscribe` or `block`), check [hantsy/angular-spring-websocket-sample](https://github.com/hantsy/angular-spring-websocket-sample/blob/master/server/src/test/kotlin/com/example/demo/WebSocketServerApplicationTests.kt), this sample project is based on Spring Boot 2.4.

**Update**: If I replace `Sinks` with a `List` to record the messages, it works. I have used the legacy `ReplayProcesssor`(Reactor suggested to update to `Sinks`) in the old Spring Boot 2.3, 2.4 projects, it worked well. Why `Sinks` blocks my `WebSocketClient` execution?

Comment: dont subscribe, your application is not the subscriber its just relaying the information forward, when you are subscribing in the middle, you are breaking the chain, all the code after the subscribe will not be run. Use `doOnNext` to do side-effects (like sending into your sinks) and then chain on `.doOnNext( ... ).then(session).flatMap(session -> session.send( ... )`

Comment: @Toerktumlare When using doOnNext in server WebSocket handler, then the send is never called.

Comment: because you need to consume whatever you have in doOnNext please read the docs or google before asking followup questions https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#doOnNext-java.util.function.Consumer-

Comment: @Toerktumlare yes, I know well about the doOnXXX callbacks, but when using it it will block sending messages back to clients. My source codes is here: https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/tree/websocket/websocket